# jQuery: focusin and keydown iterate each function multiple times

Tags: jquery, keydown, focusin

I have unordered list that have a highlighter when it selected. It only can be selected by using up and down arrow key and only when red div box is on focus.

This is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/X3vLP/

For first focus, it work perfectly fine which can move up and down within the list.
The problem come when starting on second focus, it will skip some selection on the list.

i also have tried with next and prev function

```
if ( e.keyCode == 38 ) 
    $('li.selected').removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected');
if ( e.keyCode == 40) {
    $('li.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
```

It still produce same thing.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: First tell me what you are doing after pressing Up ,Down keys?

Comment: i want to create a custom selectbox that can be control by up and down keys. but the selected list is not properly highlighted when i try to focusin multiple times

Comment: what is now done? and what you want please tell clearly ,its creating confusion.

Comment: you may want to click on the box to focusin, then move up and down arrow to select which list you want. After that focus out on the box. Then try for second time, focusin then move up and down. the problem start there. the selection list is not properly selected on the next item when move up/down is press

Comment: you mean ,if i click outside box , It jumps li using 2 steps instead of 1 ?

Comment: Yup. if i click back for the third time. it will jump 3 step and so on...

Comment: First tell meaning or working of this code =>promise().done( function(){
      $('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).eq($checkSelected).addClass('selected');
      return false;

Comment: when the each function finish iterate all li list, it will remove selected class on all li and add class to the next selected one